# How can I set max-width of table columns?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to limit all table columns to 50px. I've tried setting word-wrap, max-width in css and
style="max-width: 50px" in html as suggested in other comments. But the columns get wider than 50px.

```
table.rg-table td {
  padding: 0.35em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width:50px;   
}

<th  style="max-width: 50px;">Col 1</th>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/fr7ezcqL/

Comment: You need to add `table-layout:fixed` to your table tag stylesheet property

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The columns still get wider than 50px. https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/fr7ezcqL/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed` to `table` and `width: 50px` to `th`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 1.4;
    }
    
    .rg-container {
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 1em 0.5em;
      color: #222;
    }
    
    caption {
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    table {
      width: 650px;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      font-size: 1em;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
    
    thead {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
    }
    
    tr {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      color: #222;
    }
    
    tbody tr:hover {
      background-color: #dcf1f0 !important;
    }
    
    .zebra tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
    }
    
    th {
      font-weight: bold;
      padding: 0.35em;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      text-align: center;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    td {
      padding: 0.35em;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    td:hover {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    td:nth-of-type(2),
    td:nth-of-type(5),
    td:nth-of-type(8),
    td:nth-of-type(11) {
      text-align: center
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="rg-container">
    <table id="abc" class="rg-table zebra">
      <caption>Alpha Beta Gamma</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 1</th>
          <th>Col 2</th>
          <th>Col 3</th>
          <th>Col 4</th>
          <th>Col 5</th>
          <th>Col 6</th>
          <th>Col 7</th>
          <th>Col 8</th>
          <th>Col 9</th>
          <th>Col 10</th>
          <th>Col 11</th>
          <th>Col 12</th>
          <th>Col 13</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><b>27.04.20</b></td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>08:00</td>
          <td>09:15</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>09:30</td>
          <td>12:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>13:00</td>
          <td>15:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>15:15</td>
          <td>18:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>28.04.20</b></td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>08:00</td>
          <td>09:15</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>09:30</td>
          <td>12:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>13:00</td>
          <td>15:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>15:15</td>
          <td>18:00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><b>29.04.20</b></td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>08:00</td>
          <td>09:15</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>09:30</td>
          <td>12:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>13:00</td>
          <td>15:00</td>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>15:15</td>
          <td>18:00</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: The max-column size still gets wider than 50px.

Comment: @toms Change the table width from 100% (dynamic length) to 650px (static length -- 13 cols * 50px), see update.

Comment: Yes,, that was what I did later. I was thinking there was another solution but I guess I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Max-width not working with `td` and `th`

It makes no sense to set width for `td` if width is set for `th`

**Don't use a fixed width for all columns**

If you set all columns to a fixed width and the table cannot fill all the available space, then all columns will be added in width proportionally to fill the empty space.

**Solution:**

You can make the first and last column without data, add a `rowspan` and remove the width from it. These columns will be responsible for filling in the empty space and all fixed-width columns will always keep the specified width and will be centered in the table.

```
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th style="width: 70px;">Col 1</th>
        <th style="width: 70px;">Col 2</th>
        <th style="width: 70px;">Col 3</th>
        <th style="width: 70px;">Col 4</th>
        <th style="width: 70px;">Col 5</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan=some number></td>
        <td><b>27.04.20</b></td>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td>08:00</td>
        <td>09:15</td>
        <td>XXX</td>
        <td rowspan=some number></td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `max-width` on table elements has always been some what unclear. Different browsers have done it and still do it differently. The most reliable way to do it is to apply `max-width` to an additional element inside the table cell:

```
<th><div style="max-width: 50px">...</div></td>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use CSS

```
<style>
table.rg-table td {
  padding: 0.35em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  max-width: 50px;   
}
</style>
<th class="rg-table"> Col 1 </th>
```

Comment: Your suggested doesn't work for me. See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/fr7ezcqL/5/